# Downgrading PMML 4.4 to 4.3 version

Tags: python, java, scikit-learn, pipeline, pmml

I am trying to convert my sckit-learn model to PMML 4.3 using sklearn2pmml. I did it successfully for the version 4.4 however I need the PMML 4.3 and therefore I decided to install the version 0.56 for sklearn2pmml using the following commands:

```
pip install sklearn2pmml=0.56
```

However now when I try to create a pipeline I receive the following error:

```
Pipe_PMML = PMMLPipeline([('scaler', StandardScaler()),('classifier', LogisticRegression())])
```

> ```
>  AttributeError: 'PMMLPipeline' object has no attribute 'apply_transformer'
> ```

The newest version of sklearn2pmml is 0.76 and solve this issue but generates the PMML version 4.4. I was wondering how the previous versions used to convert the ML models in Python to PMML. Is there any way to downgrade the 4.4 version to older version?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading sklearn to 0.23.2 solved the problem for me.

Answer (score -1):

First, export your pipeline using Sklearn2PMML 0.76. Second, export your pipeline using SkLearn2PMML 0.56.

Now, take a "diff" of these two files - what are the changes? The XML namespace declaration and the value of the `PMML@version` attribute should differ, but anything else?

Once you know/understand the difference between 4.4 and 4.3 markup in your pipeline's case, write your own "downgrade" tool (or do it manually, if it's a one-time assignment).

Comment: As I said above, I received an error for the 0.56 version.

Comment: Obviously, the 0.56 version does not support the `PMMLPipeline.apply_transformer` attribute. Run the diff without this newer functionality, and see if you can figure out the MAIN DIFFERENCE between 4.3 and 4.4. Then add extras.

Comment: Any idea on how to run it without apply_transformer? Like should I downgrade the sklearn or something like this.